# How to intercept dynamic methods of domain objects with AOP or some other way? 

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I would like to wrap Domain class's dynamic methods like save() get*() with an Around advice (possibly using Spring AOP). The idea is to intercept these methods and take the decision to apply them or not. As part of it I would also like to save the return value in case the method is executed.
This logic needs to be performed as part of a plugin so that existing source code is not affected. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you having trouble doing it?

Comment: I tried doing it but it didn't work as it involves the lifecycle of plugin. At one point of time of grails lifecycle domain objects are bootstrapped and then only one should apply AOP.

Comment: This tip woreked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8388366/207791

Comment: Since I am using a canned Spring interceptor and trying to apply it to various different domain class methods, I don't want to manually code an override as is suggested in the previous comment. I want to use AOP. Has anyone worked out a real solution to this issue?